# copy paste google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

So, I made a Google Spreadsheet for a group of people to use to keep track of weekly "counts" for a large group of people on a Reddit sub.  The things I'm trying to automate are two things.  The one I'm having problems with is the one I thought would be the easiest, just copying the values from one set (G2:G200) to overwrite the values in another (E2:E200).  I'm having some other issues as well, but I'd be more interested in an explanation for what I'm doing wrong there than just an answer.  The biggest one is that this is supposed to be making a custom menu on the sheet, and I can't seem to get that working, even though I basically copied the script from the Google Tutorial for that.  I've tried the script for this two ways, one using the same script as Excel printed out when recording the same basic thing:

```
function UpdateLore_() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Only do this once per week, at end of updates.',
     ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    Range("G2:G200").Select;
    Selection.Copy;
    Range("E2:E200").Select;
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False;

  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('No Changes Made.');
  }
}
```

This returns an arror on the "Selection.PasteSpecial" line.  The other way I tried it was using what I could find online for this:

```
  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    function copyFunction () {
      var inputRange =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("G2:G200");
      var inputValue = inputRange.getValue();
      var outputRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("E2:E200");
}
```

The top part of the code looks like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Weekly Update')
      .addItem('Update for Lore', 'UpdateLore')
      .addItem('Update for XP Master', 'UpdateMaster')
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, especially with the whole "doesn't seem to change the sheet in anyway" part.  Thanks for any help

---

Got some answers and now it works, thanks for all the help:

Got it, thanks for all the help.  New code looks like this:

```
function UpdateLore() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Only do this once per week, at end of updates.',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    copyFunction ();
  }

    function copyFunction () {
      var inputRange =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("G2:G200");
      var inputValues = inputRange.getValues();
      var outputRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("E2:E200").setValues(inputValues);
    }

  if (result ==ui.Button.NO) {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('No Changes Made.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I fixed the top part, and the script now runs, at least using the "online" way, but it doesn't actually do anything, at least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add data to a sheet you need to use:

- setValue()
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#appendRow(Object))

You've got a function inside of the `if` body:

```
if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
  // User clicked "Yes".
  function copyFunction () {
   . . . . 
  }
}
```

If you want to call another function at that point, you could use:

```
if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
  // User clicked "Yes".
  copyFunction ();
};

function copyFunction () {
  . . . 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the values from the inputRange to the outputRange. Use the .setValues() on your outputRange to do this.

```
function copyFunction () {
      var inputRange =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("G2:G200");
      var inputValues = inputRange.getValues();
      var outputRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("E2:E200").setValues(inputValues);
}
```

None of this is valid apps script code:

```
Range("G2:G200").Select;
    Selection.Copy;
    Range("E2:E200").Select;
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False;
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything Spencer, none of the values changed when running the script.